# email has been set but Cannot send message without a sender address Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, registration

i want to send an email welcoming users when they register.
so in the registration controller after validation, i have my code to send email. everything set properly still couldnt send email. here is my code.

```
 protected function create(array $data): User
    {
//
        $email = request()->get('email');
        Mail::to($email)->send(new NewUserWelcomeMail());

        return User::create([

            
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
               

        ]);

    }
}
```

Comment: how you set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you used wrong sender config, to set the sender just set `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` on `.env` like below:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=your@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

or you can using `->from()` method :

```
Mail::to($email)->from('youremail@hosting.com')->send(new NewUserWelcomeMail());
```